# sqlite3.OperationalError: table responses has 5 columns but 6 values were supplied - tkinter

Tags: python, database, sqlite, tkinter

I have this error with one of my sqlite database tables that I cannot solve, even after looking online for hours. I have also tried deleting the database and starting with a new one but this did not work.

The Error: line 90, in submit1
c.execute("INSERT INTO responses VALUES (:company, :roles, :interview, :offer, :wage_offered, :start_date)",
sqlite3.OperationalError: table responses has 5 columns but 6 values were supplied

However there are 6 columns so I do not understand why this error is cropping up.

the submit1 function Code is posted below:

```
#create submit function for 
def submit1():
    # Create a databse or connect to one
    connection = sqlite3.connect('jobtracker.db')


 #Create a cursor
    c = connection.cursor()

    # Insert into table
    c.execute("INSERT INTO responses VALUES (:company, :roles, :interview, :offer, :wage_offered, :start_date)",
            {
                'company': company1.get(),
                'roles': role1.get(),
                'interview': interview.get(),
                'offer': offer.get(),
                'wage_offered': wage_offered.get(),
                'start_date': start_date.get()
            })

    # Commit changes
    connection.commit()

# Close connection
    connection.close()
```

And here is the code for the database:

```
#Creating database
conn = sqlite3.connect('jobtracker.db')

c = conn.cursor()

#Creating tables for database
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS applications (
        company text,
        role text,
        industry text,
        location text,
        wage_min integer,
        wage_max integer,
        start_date integer,
        status text
        )""")

c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS responses (
        company text,
        role text,
        interview integer,
        offer integer
        wage_offered integer,
        start_date integer
        )""")


conn.commit()

conn.close()

#create submit function for 
def submit():
    # Create a databse or connect to one
    connection = sqlite3.connect('jobtracker.db')


 #Create a cursor
    c = connection.cursor()

    # Insert into table
    c.execute("INSERT INTO applications VALUES (:company, :roles, :industry, :location, :wage_min, :wage_max, :start_date, :status)",
            {
                'company': company.get(),
                'roles': role.get(),
                'industry': industry.get(),
                'location': location.get(),
                'wage_min': wage_min.get(),
                'wage_max': wage_max.get(),
                'start_date': start_date.get(),
                'status': status.get()
            })

    # Commit changes
    connection.commit()

# Close connection
    connection.close()
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: missing comma `offer integer`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with the code. You have `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` in your table. You've probably updated your code to add a new collumn, but the database did not update since the table already exists.

Comment: Your `CREATE TABLE` statement has a syntax error in it, so that can't be the code that created the table.

Comment: Yes after implementing Mike67 comment, take a look at the `DESCRIBE <tablename>` of your table, and if out if you actually have 6 column or is it 5

Comment: Thanks for your input I appreciate it. Turns out I solved it by deleting the databse and then recreating it using just CREATE TABLE rather than CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS. Then after database was created I commented out the code so It did not create more tables.

Comment: Yes seems like the error was rather due to what @Countour-Integral said, you dont have to comment it over now, just say `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS`

Answer (score -1):

I think the table has only 5 fields
You are trying to insert 6 fields